# Is there any way to travel from the UK to the rest of the EU while a passport is being renewed?

Tags: passports

I need to renew my passport before a trip to Brazil in early April, but I have to travel from the UK to another EU country in 12 days. The earliest fast-track appointment I can get is in 6 days, so the 7-day service would not get my renewed passport back to me in time for the trip within the EU.

As far as I know my current passport is handed in, and cancelled, as part of the renewal application (I may be wrong about this - it's been 10 years since the last time) and as far as I know I cannot use any other documents for travel from the UK to other EU countries. Do I have any other option than paying for the 1-day passport service?

Comment: I think the 1 day service is your only option.

Comment: Is it a UK passport?

Comment: @phoog Yes, UK passport. I have actually booked a 1-day service now, but I'd still be interested to know whether I had any other option.

Comment: Why was this flagged as unclear?